# A function I created to return a ggplot object returns an error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a function to return a ggplot object like below

```
uni_var<-function(df,col){
  return(ggplot(df,aes(col))+geom_bar())
}
```

When I called on the mtcars data frame

```
uni_var(mtcars,cyl)
```

I get the below error

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'cyl' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation
```

What is wrong with the my function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with it. Just do:

```
uni_var(mtcars, "cyl")
```

Is this what you are going for?

```
uni_var<-function(df, col){
  col <- eval(substitute(col), df)
 return(ggplot(df, aes(col)) + geom_bar())
}

uni_var(mtcars, cyl)
```

Answer (score 4):

It might be useful to study why you need the quotes as exemplified in @claudiu-papasteri's answer. Search for non-standard evaluation in R. Take a look also at https://rlang.r-lib.org/index.html.

Try figure why this example works:

```r
library(ggplot2)

uni_var<-function(df,col){
  col <- rlang::enquo(col)
  return(ggplot(df,aes(!!col))+geom_bar())
}

uni_var(mtcars, cyl)
```

Comment: Excelent. Your are right, I think this is what he was after.